# Connection between node and mysql crash

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

I have a connection between Node and MySQL with a external database:

const connectionDB = mysql.createConnection({
host: '178.129.145.252',
port: 3306,
user: '*****',
password: '*****',
database: '*****'
})

when I execute my script to start it runs and I can view the users in a table, but later it crashes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO09b.png) anyone knows how can I connect with the external database?
Thanks

Comment: please add the complete error in the description

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not properly handle connection loss to MySQL server.

A quick solution would be to use connection pool.

```js
var db_config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'example'
};
let pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
pool.on('connection', function (conn) {
    if (conn) {
        logger.info('Connected');
    }
});

// DO SOMETHING HERE
// pool.query('QUERY GOES HERE', (err, rows) => { /* Handle query response */});
```